# Which coding style is good for set the loader in the application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coding-style

I have been developed multiple application (web & mobile), now i think it's good time to take a look in my coding style in deep and improve it. 
Every developer implement loader in their application. I am going to write 2 options in which i set loader active and inactive tell me which one is best or any other option to add loader in application.

```
// Option 1:
...
this.state={ 
 isFetchingAuthentication: false,
 isFetchingCountries: false,
 isFetchingLakes: false
}
...

...
// inside some function
this.setState({
    isFetchingAuthentication: true
})
...


// Option 2:
this.state = {
    isFetching: '' // enums ['authentication', 'countries', 'lakes']
}

...
// inside some function
this.setState({
    isFetching: 'authentication'
})  
...
```

**Note:** I am using react now, but my question is not any library specific i just want to know how the other developer add loader in application.

Comment: A coding style is very bias, I belive that any coding style is better than none, and event better if it's consistent

Comment: First, you should keep in mind that you should not repeat yourself so whatever the loader you are using that should be generic which can be reusable in your whole application and mostly loader is used when data is being fetched and for that you should aware about each and every Http request made so the best way you need to create one Http interceptor which will call ever time when any Http request is made and from there you can start your loader and once you received the response you can stop loader so one place you will write the code and applicable for entire app.

Answer (score 0):

`// Option 1:
...
this.state={
 isLoading:false
}
...`

`...
// inside some function
this.setState({isLoading:true});
...`

This is the easiest and best way to do it. This is mainly if your product/application has a single/commom loader.